# How to import dependencies from other folder?

Tags: python, import, directory, python-import, sys

I have to folders A and B. In folder A is my main.py. In folder B there are a few classes in different scripts: B1.py, B2.py, B3.py…

I want to import a class from B1.py. I got that to work with sys.path.append and so on. But the problem is that the B1.py script imports other classes from the other scripts in folder B:

`from B2 import classB2 from B3 import classB3`

When I try to import ClassB1 in my main.py (which is in folder A) it can‘t import the classes classB2, classB3, etc. How do I fix that?

I tried to add B.B1 and B.B2 etc. in the B1.py,… documents. This works but I am supposed to not alter the code in B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tidy way to do this would be creating a package ([*Packaging python Projects*](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/)) and then from the directory with the `setup.py` file in it running `pip install`. to install it on your local machine. This would allow you to `import` as you would with any installed module.

For a quick and dirty solution you can add the path of the desired module's directory to the start of the `sys.path` variable in python and it will search there when looking to `import`.

`import` statements in b1 wont be broken this way.

Here is a test case in a folder A where each module in B imports the next and calls its hello function

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, '/root/projects/learning/B')

import b1

b1.hellob1()
```

Here is the output

```bash
# /bin/python3 /root/projects/learning/A/a1.py
Hello World from b1.py
Hello World from b2.py
Hello World from b3.py
```